# i7-8700k non-OC turbo boost frequency / single core performance

Tags: intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

My 8700k has lower then average single core performance related to other non-oc 8700k bench results, while multicore is OK. I've noticed frequency never rises above 4.3 ghz, I never see promised turbo boost 4.7ghz. Mobo: asus z370-f gaming.

Looks like turbo boost isn't working properly. Any suggestions?

my 8700k results:
[image: my 8700k results]

average non-overclocked 8700k single core bench:
[image: 8700k average non oc]

cpu-z bench:
[image: cpu-z]

bios:
[image: bios - overall]
[image: bios - oc settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, now my 8700k performs on par with cpu.userbenchmark results. The reason was, for some reason, the motherboard bios (asus z370-f gaming) had CPU C-states as disabled, which didn't let the CPU boost to more then 4.3Ghz.

After enabling, CPU boosts to 4.6Ghz (though I never got advertised 4.7Ghz) it puts it's benchmark results on par with other non-overclocked results.

Regarding CPU-Z results, it looks like those are outdated, before Spectre / Meltdown patches, as on forums and reviews 550 is not an average for non-OC single clock CPU, it's closer to 500.